# CosmosDb use of continuation token while read operation

Tags: c#, cosmos

Team, I am using cosmos db for storing unique codes so my requirement is to get unique codes for single user. With the help of Continuation token feature provided by cosmos db I am able to get unique codes.
Now I have a situation for getting unique codes when same continuation token is used by two users. Below is scenario

Example

User 1 --Getting top 10 codes with "{abc}" continuation token.

User 2 --Getting top 10 codes with "{abc}" continuation token.

I do want to give same codes to User 2.Is there a way to prevent a request from using token continuation used by One user only?

Comment: Do not share the continuation token with the other user, that's how you can prevent.

Comment: I am not sharing continuation token, we are using it internally for pagination purpose.

Comment: I think I got confused with this `I do want to give same codes to User 2.` in your question. What exact issue you are facing? What problem you are trying to solve?